# How can I run a .desktop file?

Tags: shell, xdg-open

I'm trying to write a script that launches the default application for a given mime type. For example, I would like to say `my-script text/plain` and have it open KWrite for me.

What I know is that you can use xdg-mime to query what is the default application for a given mime type

```
$ xdg-mime query default text/plain
org.kde.kwrite.desktop
```

However, I don't know what is the command I can use to launch KWrite given `org.kde.kwrite.desktop`. How can I do that? Is having the name of the desktop file enough or do I also need to find out where it is stored (`/usr/share/applications`, `.local/share/applications`, etc)?

---

By the way, I don't think I can solve my original problem using `xdg-open` because XDG open expects to receive a filename or URL as a parameter and I want to be able to launch my applications without needing to pass a filename. For example, I want to be able to open the text editor on a blank  file buffer or open my web browser on its home page.

Comment: How is this easier with a Python script?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[This answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/5172/running-a-desktop-file-in-the-terminal) over on askubuntu.com covers many different ways to solve the problem. The one that was the closes to doing what I wanted was the `gtk-launch` command:

```
gtk-launch org.kde.kwrite.desktop
```

One thing I like about `gtk-launch` is that it can find the appropriate desktop file even if you only give it the name.

Comment: Use `kioclient5 exec /path/to/file.desktop` on KDE. See https://askubuntu.com/a/425178